# Google Calendar API JAVA Update event not working suddenly

Tags: java, api, google-calendar-api

`Event event = service.events().get("primary", eventID).execute();

```
        //set new start time
        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(assignmentTask.getStartDate().substring(0,10)+"T09:00:00+05:30");
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(startDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Asia/Colombo");
        event.setStart(start);

        //set new end time
        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(assignmentTask.getFinishDate().substring(0,10)+"T17:00:00+05:30");
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Asia/Colombo");
        event.setEnd(end);

        //update event
        service.events().update("primary", event.getId(), event).execute();`
```

i use the google calendar API in my application to add and update calendar events. the API worked perfectly yesterday. When i rechecked the function today, the event did not get updated. i did not change my code from after checking yesterday, so i cant understand why it suddenly won't work. 
Shedding some light on the matter would be greatly appreciated. what i can do to fix this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your code? Also: do you get an error message? Please post them as well.

Comment: No i do not get any error messages, the code flow continues. but i don't see the change in the calendar.

Comment: Without more details, it is difficult to help. It could be anything.

Comment: i posted my code. this worked perfectly yesterday. not sure what happened.

Comment: this code has been working as expected since February 2018. it is for my student assignment due next week. your input would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Calendar API doesn't allow the events to be updated more than once. so I just deleted the event and inserted a new one in its place.